# Split value in javascript in group of one, two and three

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, split

I am trying to find a regular expression to split this value:

`307AF53DA584`

into this:

`3:07:AF5:3DA:584`

I tried this: `var [V, A, L, U, E] = ( myString.split( /(?=(?:...)(?:..)*$)/ ) );`

But got this result: `3:07:AF:53:DA`

The value will always be 12 characters.

Thanks!

Comment: Split or replace? If the split criterion is length of the chunks, why use regex? [Use `substr()`.](https://jsfiddle.net/wgn93683/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply replace the current string with the value

```js
const regex = /(\S{1})(\S{2})(\S{3})(\S{3})(\S{3})/g;
const str = '307AF53DA584';
const subst = '$1:$2:$3:$4:$5';

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking! I still have difficulties with regex. Thanks

Comment: Also it could be your regex only `var [V, A, L, U, E] = ( myString.split( /(\S{1})(\S{2})(\S{3})(\S{3})(\S{3})/g ) );` it works too!